# How to add array values to multivalued fields on solr?

Tags: php, solr, multivalue

I am building a tagged based search engine, so I need to add my arrays to a multivalued field, I searched the topic but could not find anything about that, my array is like this,

```
$sub["E"] = array("as","bs","ds","fd");
```

I tried $doc->addField("cat",$sub["E"]); did not work and I don't want to put this in foreach loop and get 5 or 6 addField object, If you can share with me any shortcuts, I will be happy, thank you :)

Comment: why not put in `foreach()` ? Or you'll have to do that anyway in the `AddField` code to make it able to handle arrays and not just strings.